# CSS transition a single character

Tags: css

I'm looking for help on how to transition a single character on a button when the button itself is hovered over as seen below:

[image]

All my attempts so far have just resulted in the whole button shifting to the right rather than the single chevron.

Thanks

Comment: Use the `::after` pseudo-element.

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's easy, You have to use pseudo-element for it eg:

> Note: Don't decrease width or instead of button will move instead of the animated thing

```css
.button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
```

```html
<button class="button"><span>Hover </span></button>
```